# Spring MVC configuration with @EnableWebMvc and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter for static resources location causes problems with "forward:" and "redirect:"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot hello world for web and some confusion with configuration:

Spring version: 1.2.6.RELEASE

My project structure:

[image]

I need to supply some static content so I decided to redefine the source directory for this type of content in some custom `WebConfig` class (for study purposes):

Javadoc for `@EnableWebMvc` say:

> Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring
>   MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport
>
> To customize the imported configuration, implement the interface
>   WebMvcConfigurer or more likely extend the empty method base class
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and override individual methods, e.g.:

So the next configuration-class was born:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/r/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/r/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/favicon.ico").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/r/favicon.ico");
    }
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/r/diploma/index.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }
}
```

And if run the app and try to visit http://localhost:8080/
I get the next exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/r/diploma/index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

**But** if i remove the `@EnableWebMvc` from my WebConfig, I got my index.html in browser.
So what is the reason of such behavior?

Actually I have a production project which I using as example to study and it has both `@EnableWebMvc` & `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` on `WebConfig`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a `ViewResolver` to resolves your views in `WebConfig`, something like this:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
    return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
}
```

When you're adding `@EnableWebMvc`, you're turning off all of the spring boot's web auto configurations, which automatically configures such a resolver for you. By removing the annotation, auto configuration will turn on again and the auto configurated `ViewResolver` solves the problem.