# How to serve static resources in Spring boot with @EnableWebMvc

Tags: spring-boot

Cracking head over this. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) says:

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

### Minimal example:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

And create one directory `/src/main/resources/public` placing static resources there. When I run the application I only get 404. When I **remove** `@EnableWebMvc` resources are served as expected.

### Attempted (and failed) remedies

```
/**
 * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addResourceHandlers(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry)
 */
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**").addResourceLocations("/public/");
}
```

In the `application.properties` added:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/
```

### The question

So my question: What do I need to configure to serve static resource when I want to use the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation?

Comment: Seems like @EnableWebMvc doesn't work well with Spring Boot. See: https://techblog.bozho.net/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-common-use-cases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) you mentionned, it says :

> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your
>   own `@Configuration` annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`.

You should try to use `@EnableWebMvc` with your configuration instead of your Spring boot application.
There's an example of this in this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-enable).

> ### Enabling the MVC Java Config or the MVC XML Namespace
>
> To enable MVC Java config add the annotation `@EnableWebMvc` to one of
>   your `@Configuration` classes:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebMvc
> public class WebConfig {
> }
> ```

Also in these examples :

- [Customizing the Provided Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-customize)
- [Conversion and Formatting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-conversion)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That "complete control" threw me of the rails. An added sentence: "and btw the default configuration and behavior will not load anymore" would make it clearer. I'm happy with the defaults, so I guess I'll remove the annotation

Answer (score 1):

You should configure a `ViewResolver` something like below along with your ResourceHandlers. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982199/5296354)

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
   return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
}
```